# Linux dualboot with windows

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub

I'm formatted my SSD and installed windows7, after I installed manjaro linux with GRUB2. In GRUB2 there is no windows7 submenu. So I'm executed `update-grub`, it returned no errors, but windows7 wasn't found, so I added it through editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
submenu "Windows 7" {
 regexp -s root '\((.+)\)' "$cmdpath"
 chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

How to add windows7 in grub?
There is my disks partitioning:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL            UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                 
├─sda1 ntfs   System Reserved  6874CCE474CCB65A                     
├─sda2 ntfs                    34F0E721F0E6E7D6                     
├─sda3 vfat                    52FA-B552                            /boot/efi
└─sda4 ext4                    da2e349a-50aa-4bda-9770-32d431bb0881 /
sdb                                                                 
├─sdb1 ntfs   My Files         F26C58206C57DDC3                     
├─sdb2 ntfs   Windows Programs 0EBA345BBA34418F                     
└─sdb3 ext4                    a6064200-2841-4f0b-8c69-7fbe41993fd4 /home
```

sda1 and sda2 were created automaticly by windows7 installer. I am guessing what sda1 is windows bootloader, and on sda2 windows installed

```
>>> sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
>>> ls /mnt
Boot  bootmgr  BOOTSECT.BAK  'System Volume Information'

>>> sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
>>> ls /mnt
Boot          'Documents and Settings'  Portable         'Program Files (x86)'        Users
bootmgr       pagefile.sys              ProgramData      '$Recycle.Bin'               Windows
BOOTSECT.BAK  PerfLogs                  'Program Files'  'System Volume Information'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partition of hd0 was mbr, not gpt. I'm reinstalled both OS with correct partition type and it was solved the problem